# How to set in android viewflipper from code to be visible view by index?

Tags: android

How to set in android viewflipper from code to be visible view with index 1 ?
In code I have something like this

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
    android:gravity="top" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/index_0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/index_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/index_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>
</ViewFlipper>
```

and from code I need to make visible view by integer which represents index of view inside view flipper

Answer (score 0):

This will set your currently displaying view in a flipper.

```
flipper.setDisplayedChild(\*index of view you want to display*\);
```

Additionally you can use

```
flipper.getDisplayedChild();
```

to get currently displaying child.
Good luck

Comment: Is the index 0-based? You could add that information as well